# Make 2 TextViews have the same height

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, android-layout-weight

I have 2 TextView one on top of the other. When they have the same text they have the same height but when one has more text from the other he will get bigger.

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                    android:paddingTop="12dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="Math, Civics"
                        android:id="@+id/teaches"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#A4D34A" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="Computer Science"
                        android:id="@+id/learns"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#D22ACE" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="5$/hour"
                        android:id="@+id/rate" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:text="Start Chat"
                            android:id="@+id/textView9"
                            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                            android:textStyle="italic"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
```

How can I make them stay in the same height no matter what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options: You can provide equal weights to the two textviews

```
<TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"/>
<TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

OR You can use give **fixed heights** to both views.
OR You can set **MaxLines**(Maximmum lines) attribute for the text view to be of a particular value.

Comment: This is the correct answer, I personally put and the maxLines attribute in the declaration of the two TextViews

Answer (score 1):

Define a fixed value for yout *layout_height* like *24dp* or something best in an dimens.xml like that:

```
<dimen name="textview_height">24dp</dimen>
```

and in your layout put both *layout_height* to :

```
@dimen/textview_height
```

Another option would be to set the first to set both to *wrap_content* and get the *MeasuredHeight* from both of them, then take the greater value and apply it to both *TextViews*